# Existence proof of continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Does there exists a continuous linear functional $L\in (C_b([0,\infty)))^*$ such that $L(f) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ whenever the limit exists?

Comment: Simple application of Hahn-Banach. On the subspace of functions for which this limit exists define the functional by the limit.

Comment: ok, but what about the sublinear function as bound for the functional you mentioned above?

Comment: The norm of the ambient space.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the application. especially the sublinear function... what is is exactly and what is the sense of it?

Comment: I have the pleasure to state the Hahn-Banach theorem for you (because you don't seem to be able to find it on the net): A bounded linear functional $f$ defined on a subspace of a normed space can be extended to a bounded linear functional $g$ on the whole space (the normed space) having the same norm as $f$.